# Issue with POST request to Flask endpoint not working

Tags: javascript, python, flask, post, request

I am developing a chatbot feature in my web application using Flask and JavaScript. The chatbot should send a message to a Flask endpoint when the user presses the send button. However, the POST request doesn't seem to be working as expected and I get this message showing up on my console:

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:5001/;/predict 404 (NOT FOUND)
```

I have a Flask endpoint defined as follows in app.py:

```
@app.post("/predict")
def predict():
    text = request.get_json().get("message")
    # TO-DO: check if text is valid
    response = get_response(text)
    message = {"answer": response}
    return jsonify(message)
```

In my app.js file, I am making the POST request using the Fetch API when the send button is pressed:

```
fetch($SCRIPT_ROOT + "/predict", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({ message: text1 }),
      mode: "cors",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    })
      .then((r) => r.json())
      .then((r) => {
        let msg2 = { name: "Sam", message: r.answer };
        this.messages.push(msg2);
        this.updateChatText(chatBox);
        textField.value = "";
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error:", error);
        this.updateChatText(chatBox);
        textField.value = "";
      });
  }
```

However, the POST request doesn't seem to be working, and I'm not receiving the expected response. Here's what I've checked so far:

I've verified that the fetch URL ($SCRIPT_ROOT + "/predict") evaluates to the correct endpoint URL where my Flask application is running and listening for POST requests.
I've checked the Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) settings, and both the server-side (Flask) and client-side domains are properly configured to allow the request.
I've confirmed that my Flask application is running and accessible, as I can successfully access other endpoints.
I've reviewed the Flask server-side code, but I can't find any obvious errors or issues.
I would appreciate any suggestions or insights into why the POST request is not working as expected. Is there anything I might be missing or any additional steps I should take to debug this issue?

Please note that the POST request is specifically triggered when the user presses the send button in the chatbot interface. If there are any specific considerations related to this event triggering the request, please let me know.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: You mentioned that you are not getting the expected response. What kind of response are you getting ?

Comment: Hi, this is the response I get when I click the send button on my console "POST http://127.0.0.1:5001/;/predict 404 (NOT FOUND)"

Comment: You have an addition `;` in your URL. Your `$SCRIPT_ROOT` seems to be defined incorrectly.

Comment: go to your network tab in your inspect and check if request is sending correctly